# Possible to forfeit a sanctioned equity (RSX) to realize a tax loss?

Tags: taxes

So I owned the Van Eck Russia ETF (RSX) which has dropped by 90% since I bought it, and is also halted due to sanctions. It would be great if I could sell it for $0 or otherwise get rid of it. Is there any way to do this or am I "stuck" holding it indefinitely?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to check with your broker. Many brokers will allow you selling it to them, potentially for a commission. Look for "worthless security liquidation" form, or reach out to your brokerage customer service. [This (a bit dated) article](https://www.kiplinger.com/article/investing/t052-c001-s001-how-to-sell-worthless-stock.html) explains it.